# Oracle 12 PCTUSED & PCTFREE and INITRANS & MAXTRANS

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I'm working with Oracle 12c, and I want to ask about this parameters in Create Table.

My Application in several Tables will do a lot of deletes and inserts, I think this parameters are not correct

```
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
```

The Effects of Specifying a Smaller `PCTUSED`, reduces processing costs incurred during `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements but a larger `PCTUSED` increases the processing cost during `INSERT` and `UPDATE`.

I think it's not correct use 0 for `PCTUSED`: The default value for `PCTUSED` is 40 percent. according with the doc.

Another point in the DOC:

> Assume that a table is usually accessed by many users at the same
>   time. In this case, you might consider preallocating transaction entry
>   space by using a high INITRANS. This eliminates the overhead of having
>   to allocate transaction entry space, as required when the object is in
>   use. Also, allow a higher MAXTRANS so that no user has to wait to
>   access necessary data blocks.

In my case it will be a Web app with many users <100 working in the same time.

Comment: There isn't a single correct value; if there was it wouldn't be configurable. Are you asking what values you should use for your specific scenario?

Comment: Yes, for this reasson I say: WebApplication with <100 Users, with half part of the Schema (Tables) working with a high average of Inserts-deletes and updates

Comment: OK, but that's not enough information, and it's not on-topic for this site anyway I'm afraid. Look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/pfgrf_build_db.htm#TGDBA94152), [this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses007.htm), etc. Also check if you're using ASSM. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameters are probably fine.  As Alex Poole mentioned, read the [phsyical_attributes_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses007.htm#SQLRF30011) section of the manual.  Make sure you look at the 12c version, the quote in the question appears to have disappeared after Oracle 9i.

Ignore `PCTUSED`, `INITRANS`, and `MAXTRANS`:

- **PCTUSED:** "This parameter is not useful and is ignored for objects with automatic segment-space management."
- **INITRANS:** "In general, you should not change the INITRANS value from its default."
- **MAXTRANS:** "This parameter has been deprecated."

`PCTFREE` is probably the only parameter worth thinking about, and the default of 10 is likely fine.

It's good to be a little skeptical of the manual.  But I wouldn't make any changes to those parameters without a fully reproducible test case demonstrating a real difference.

Comment: Pretty sure the docs are incorrect when they state that PCTFREE is ignored.  Perhaps newer versions of the docs do not state that.   It is easy to prove - create a table with small rows using PCTFREE 0.  Insert a few hundred rows via a single session.  Now start up some job with 100 sessions trying to update those rows.  There will be ITL waits, the consequence of not allowing more room for the ITL (interested transaction list) to grow within the block, due to PCTFREE 0 allowing the block to completely fill with data.

Comment: @JaredStill I think you may be confusing PCTFREE with PCTUSED? I agree that PCTFREE still matters.

Comment: After rereading, yes, you are correct @JohnHeller.  I see it was PCTUSED that was considered useless.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to change the INITRANS value to much higher than the default of 1 for tables and 2 for indexes. We have an OLTP system that will 'hot block' i.e. cause majore contention headaches if the INITRANS is not allowed to be higher. The value we set is 50. this enables multi access to the blocks at the same time and, thus, prevents 'hot blocking'.

Comment: Setting INITRANS to a higher value allows more sessions to obtain a DML lock.  It doesn't do anything for 'hot blocking', as that is a different problem.  Hot blocks occur when many sessions want simultaneous access to teh same block.